# Gitlab API add SSH-key

Tags: ssh, gitlab, openssh

I've problems adding an SSH key to my gitlab server trough the API (It works well trough the webpage).

Gitlab information:
[image: Gitlab Information]

I came across [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/1289) ([which was fixed here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/519/diffs))  which was related to an "wrong" openssh implementation. They've fixed this in milestone 7.10. Only thing... My server has openssh 6.6 installed:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

Now, I don't know if that fix is backwards compatible or not, but maybe good to mention.

Also, the logs show no warning or errors or whatsoever. The /tmp/gitlab_key* files are generated on the server:
[image: output of /tmp/gitlab_key*]

The problem I'm facing is that gitlab **can't create the fingerprint** trough the API. This is the responce I get from the API:

```
{
    "message": {
        "fingerprint": ["cannot be generated"]
    }
}
```

So right now I have no idea what the problem could be. I've been struggling with this for almost a week now, so I really hope that his problem could be fixed.

-just for the record, here's the script I'm using to add the ssh-key trough the API

```sh
#!/bin/bash
 
jsonFile="jsonResponce"
 
echo `curl http://gitserver/api/v3/session --data 'login=****&password=****'` > $jsonFile
userToken=$(jq '.private_token' $jsonFile)
 
finalUserToken=$(echo "$userToken" | tr -d '"')
 
echo "user token: $finalUserToken"
 
# Below key is for testing, will use output of cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub later on
# sshKey="ssh-rsa AAAAB3N***** ****@***.com
 
# curl --data "private_token=$userToken&title=keyName&key=$sshKey" "http://gitserver/api/v3/user/keys"
 
rm $jsonFile
```

Comment: I don't see any errors here, or any question. Can you clarify what you're asking about?

Comment: @larsks hmm, I'm sorry. I've added the error I get. Hope that it's clear? Or do you need more information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`id_rsa.pub` is base64 encoded file, it contains `+` character

http post with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, need encode it's content preventing `+` being convert to   (space)

try

```
curl --data-urlencode "key=$key_pub" --data-urlencode "title=$hostname" \
http://gitlabserver/api/v3/user/keys?private_token=$Token
```

see: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23152871/719995)

Answer (score 5):

Improving on @Mathlight's answer the following snippet uploads public ssh key to [gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com)

```
curl -X POST -F "private_token=${GITLAB_TOKEN}" -F "title=$(hostname)" -F "key=$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)" "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/user/keys"
```

Comment: BTW, updated `"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/user/keys"` API route works too (is necessary in version >= 15 of GitLab).

Answer (score 2):

*OP here*

In the mean time I've updated the server to version 8.8 and changed the `curl` code a bit and now it's working like a charm:

```
curl -X POST -F "private_token=${userToken}" -F "title=${sshName}" -F "key=${sshKey}" "${gitServer}/user/keys"
```

*Just in case anybody needs this in the future...*